# Anaconda Navigator (2.0.4 --> 2.1.1) won't update on Windows 10

Tags: anaconda

I am just wondering if anyone has had the issue stated in the title.

**Context**

I am currently on anaconda navigator version 2.0.4 (this was a July 2021 release if I am correct), and I am looking to upgrade the navigator to version 2.1.1 (the latest release as of this posting). My OS is Windows 10.

**Problem**

When I update from the navigator itself (on the "upgrade now" button), the update says it's running but never finishes (I sat about an hour before dismissing it).

I tried manually installing the update, but it just tells me that "all requested packages are already installed" (see below)

[image]

I even tried going into anaconda powershell prompt, deactivating conda and updating it, but still the same issue ("all requested packages are already installed"), see below:

[image]

I am wondering if anyone has the same issue as I do? Are there any more potential fixes I could try? Preferably one in which I don't have to uninstall and reinstall anaconda. The navigator is important to me because that's where I install all my packages into the various virtual environments. I can work around it if it's unfixable but I'd rather have it working straight. Appreciate the help.

Comment: from command line update all the modules by running `conda update --all`

Comment: I had the same problem then I tried @eshirvana solution and it worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had a simmilar problem. I was trying to upgrade from version 1.9.12. I tried severeal times with this sequence of commands:

conda update conda
conda update --all
conda deactivate
conda update anaconda-navigator

But it was unsuccesful. anaconda-navigator did not upgrade and there was still an upgrade button in the navigator app, which should upgrade to the latest version, which was 2.1.2 at the time. Clicking
this button was also unsuccesful.

Then i found this https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/update-version/, how to install a specific version of a package.

I tried this command:

conda install anaconda-navigator=2.1.2

And it worked. The output of the command was suggesting something was wrong with repositories:

Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: done

But it finnished successful. At the end I also did this.

conda update conda
conda update --all

And now a have everything updated to tha latest version, including anaconda-navigator. I hope this somehow helps.

Answer (score 0):

Right click the shortcut of the navigator (or the icon in Start) and choose "Run as administartor".

Once the navigator opens run the upgrade